# Function to return an interface not working in lambda function

Tags: java, function, lambda

I'm trying to get my function to print out how many times a number is found within an array of doubles using lambda functions. It seems like my function "counter" won't go into the lambda function.

I'm trying to print out the number of times the lambda function counts the number passed in (value).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ws7_t2 {
   static int counter = 0;
   static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
   @FunctionalInterface
   public interface ArrayProcessor {
       double apply( double[] array );
   }
   
   public static ArrayProcessor counter( double value ) { 
       ArrayProcessor count = (arr) ->{
           System.out.println("2");
           for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
               if(arr[i] == value) {
                   counter++;
               }
               System.out.println(counter);
           }
           return counter;
       };
       System.out.println(counter);
       return count;
       
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       int indexes = 5;
       int currInd = 0;
       double array[] = new double[indexes];
       
       /*Add Values*/
       while(currInd != indexes) {
       System.out.println("Add value into the array (Index " + currInd +"): ");
       array[currInd] = input.nextDouble();
       currInd++;
       }
   
       /*Find Max Value*/
       ArrayProcessor maxVal = (arr) ->{
           double max = 0;
           for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
               if(arr[i] > max) {
                   max = arr[i];
               }
           }
           return max;
           
       };
       /*Find Min Value*/
       ArrayProcessor minVal = (arr) ->{
           double min = 99999;
           for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
               if(arr[i] < min) {
                   min = arr[i];
               }
           }
           return min;
           
       };
       /*Find the Sum*/
       ArrayProcessor findSum = (arr) ->{
           double sum = 0;
           for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                   sum += arr[i];
               }
           return sum;
       };
       /*Find the Average*/
       ArrayProcessor findAverage = (arr) ->{
           double average = 0;
           int counter = 0;
           for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                   average += arr[i];
                   counter++;
               }
           average = average/counter;
           return average;
       };
       System.out.println("Max value in array: " + maxVal.apply(array));
       System.out.println("Min value in array: " + minVal.apply(array));
       System.out.println("Sum of values in the array: " + findSum.apply(array));
       System.out.println("Average of array: " + findAverage.apply(array));
       System.out.println("Which value do you want to count how many times were found in the array?: ");
       double findNum = input.nextDouble();
       counter(findNum);   

   }

}
```

This code is simply trying to find the max value, min value, sum and average. After that, it displays the information to the user, then asks which number wants to be found in the array.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You just missed to use apply `counter(findNum);`  to `double count = counter(findNum).apply(array);`

to make code more readable you can use streams

```java
import java.util.*;

public class ws7_t2 {
    static int counter = 0;
   static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

   @FunctionalInterface
   public interface ArrayProcessor {
       double apply( double[] array );
   }
   
   public static ArrayProcessor counter( double value ) { 
       return (arr) ->  Arrays.stream(arr).filter(e-> e == value).count();
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       int indexes = 5;
       int currInd = 0;
       double array[] = new double[indexes];

       /*Add Values*/
       while(currInd != indexes) {
        System.out.println("Add value into the array (Index " + currInd +"): ");
        array[currInd] = input.nextDouble();
        currInd++;
       }
   
       /*Find Max Value*/
       ArrayProcessor maxVal = (arr) -> Arrays.stream(arr).max().orElse(Double.NaN);

       /*Find Min Value*/
       ArrayProcessor minVal = (arr) -> Arrays.stream(arr).min().orElse(Double.NaN);

       /*Find the Sum*/
       ArrayProcessor findSum = (arr) -> Arrays.stream(arr).sum();

       /*Find the Average*/
       ArrayProcessor findAverage = (arr) ->Arrays.stream(arr).average().orElse(Double.NaN);

       System.out.println("Max value in array: " + maxVal.apply(array));
       System.out.println("Min value in array: " + minVal.apply(array));
       System.out.println("Sum of values in the array: " + findSum.apply(array));
       System.out.println("Average of array: " + findAverage.apply(array));
       System.out.println("Which value do you want to count how many times were found in the array?: ");
       double findNum = input.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("frequency of element : " + counter(findNum).apply(array));   

   }

}
```